# Why does Python json.dumps fail on mixed utf-8 & unicode strings?

Tags: python, json, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Python (2.x) builtin json library supports encoding both unicode & utf-8 encoded (non-ASCII) strings - but apparently not at the same time. Try:

`import json; json.dumps([u'Ä', u'Ä'.encode("utf-8")], ensure_ascii=False)`

and see it raise a UnicodeDecodeError. Whereas both:

`json.dumps([u'Ä'], ensure_ascii=False)`

and

`json.dumps([u'Ä'.encode("utf-8")], ensure_ascii=False)`

...work ok.

Why does JSON encoding of data with both unicode & utf-8 encoded (non-ASCII) strings produce an UnicodeDecodeError? My Python site encoding is ASCII.

Comment: BTW, at least ujson handles this kind of case just fine.

Comment: `json.dumps(['Ä'.encode("utf-8")], ensure_ascii=False)` does not work ok.

Comment: Which Python version? I think you should use `u'Ä'.encode("utf-8")` (note the u!)

Comment: @luoluo, RemcoGerlich that was a typo- fixed, thanks for catching that!

Comment: @Petri: you should fix it on the other line too.

Comment: Updated my answer with a fix.

Comment: "UTF-8 encoded" is not a string. It's just a sequence of bytes.

Comment: @Matthias: on Python2 it is; try type(u"Pää".encode("utf-8"))

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because it doesn't know what kind of output string to produce.

In my Python 2.7:

```
>>> json.dumps([u'Ä'], ensure_ascii=False)
u'["\xc4"]'
```

(a Unicode string)

and

```
>>> json.dumps([u'Ä'.encode("utf-8")], ensure_ascii=False)
'["\xc3\x84"]'
```

(a UTF8-encoded byte string)

So if you give it UTF8-encoded byte strings, it produces a UTF8-encoded byte string JSON, and if you give it Unicode strings, it produces a Unicode JSON.

If you mix them, it can't do both.

To fix this, you can give an explicit encoding argument (even though the default is correct) and it seems that it makes the result a unicode string always then:

```
>>> import json; json.dumps([u'Ä', u'Ä'.encode("utf-8")], ensure_ascii=False, encoding="UTF8")
u'["\xc4", "\xc4"]'
```

Comment: note: the "fix" doesn't work if you use `encoding='utf-8'` instead of `encoding='UTF8'`. To avoid the issue, you should pass Unicode strings to `json`.

Comment: I would like to accept this answer but I don't think the reason is "it does not know what to produce". I remember reading somewhere that there's some implicit decoding involved in this kind of situation... ?

Comment: I know what you mean, but it was a quick answer while at work and I won't have time to look into what is actually happening until later. Just leave it open, maybe someone else will come up with something a bit more technical :-)